# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactDebugCurrentFrame' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dom

I upgraded react to latest version but it seems not working. I get the below error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactDebugCurrentFrame' of undefined
```

Below are my dependencies

```
     "dependencies": {
          "react": "^16.6.0",
          "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue after I upgrade react-dom version as same as react.

```
       "dependencies": {
          "react": "^16.6.0",
          "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
       }
```

Also the other possible case for the issue is that react-dom should not be installed as dev dependencies. Both react and react-dom should be installed with flag —save or -s like below

```
       npm i -s react react-dom
```